# Is there any shape with a flat base and an opening at the top that has a smaller surface area to volume ratio than a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, optimization, spheres, spherical-geometry

I am trying to optimize the shape of a food container with an opening at the top (meaning lowest surface area to volume ratio) that can be eaten from but I have no idea what shape can replace a cylinder. I have already tried shapes related to hemispheres such as a bowl or indented hemisphere but I have realized that a normal hemisphere (without modifications to its shape which will always increase the surface area to volume ratio), has a greater surface area to volume ratio than a cylinder.

Also, the shape should not be a sphere with a hole at the top as it would be hard to eat from (although it is an answer to the question).

Thanks everybody!

[For Misha Lavrov](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OigEl.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure a hemisphere is better than an open cylinder.

Comment: Yes, you get a ratio of $\frac 3r$ for both the hemisphere and the open cylinder. However, if you want to minimize the surface area for a given volume, the hemisphere will be better: it will achieve that volume for a larger value of $r$ (because its volume is $\frac23 \pi r^3$, and the cylinder's is $\pi r^3$) and therefore its value of $\frac 3r$ will be smaller.

Comment: Ohh I see now. Thanks a lot!